# Kendo Grid: Server Side Paging with HttpClient rather than Http

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm having difficulty with server side paging with HttpClient rather than the old Http.

Where I'm struggling is with the removal of the ".map" and processing the response to the GridDataResult interface

An old service would look like this

```
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public fetch(state: DataSourceRequestState): Observable<DataResult> {
    const queryStr = `${toDataSourceRequestString(state)}`; // Serialize the state

    return this.http
      .get(`${this.BASE_URL}?${queryStr}`)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .map(({ results, count }) => /
        (<GridDataResult>
          data: results,
          total: count,
        })
      )
    }
```

How might my new service look?

I thought it would look something like this but can't get it to work

```
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public fetch(state: DataSourceRequestState): Observable<DataResult> {
      const queryStr = `${toDataSourceRequestString(state)}`; // Serialize the state

      return this.http
        .get<GridDataResult>(`${this.BASE_URL}?${queryStr}`)
        .map(({ results, count }) =>
          (<GridDataResult>{             
            data: results,
            total: count,
          })
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct method

To get it working I mapped the data to any ((data:any) and then was able to use the server side paging

```
return this.http
  .get<GridDataResult>(`${this.BASE_URL}?${queryStr}`)
  .map((data: any) =>
    (<GridDataResult>{
      data: data.results,
      total: data.count,
    })
  )
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as this, but was fixed by getting the data and total from a slightly different location.

```
return this.httpClient
  .get<DataResult>(`${this.BASE_URL}/EmailAccounts?${queryStr}`) // Send the state to the server
  .map( (data: any) =>
    (<GridDataResult>{
      data: data.result.data,
      total: data.result.total,
    })
  )
```

I looked at the data returned from the api with [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to find the location of the data and total. This works with **dotnet core 2.0 controller** and the **Kendo.Mvc.Extensions** `ToDataSourceResult` function.

```
// GET: api/EmailAccounts
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<JsonResult> EmailAccounts([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(await _context.EmailAccounts.ToDataSourceResultAsync(request));
}
```

Format of my data returned.

```
{
    "result":
    {
        "data":[
            {"id":1,"hostName":"TestHost","protocall":1,"port":336,"useSsl":true,"username":"usrname","password":"112345"},
            {"id":2,"hostName":"TestHost","protocall":1,"port":336,"useSsl":true,"username":"usrname","password":"112345"}
        ],
        "total":2,
        "aggregateResults":null,
        "errors":null
    },
    "id":26,
    "exception":null,
    "status":5,
    "isCanceled":false,
    "isCompleted":true,
    "isCompletedSuccessfully":true,
    "creationOptions":8,
    "asyncState":null,
    "isFaulted":false
}
```